# Using Regular expression how to check the Empty DateTime Value in my MVC2 validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How to validate Datetime property in my MVC2 Validation.

I have telerik datetime picker to validate

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("EffectiveDate")%>

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "EffectiveDate Must not be empty!")]
            public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        }
```

if I use this code I am not able to validation the EffevtiveDate. Because I am just suspecting that effective date showing as "" instead of null.

how to check "" value using regular expressiong here?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your model property a nullable DateTime:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "EffectiveDate Must not be empty!")]
public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

Then the `[Required]` attribute should be enough to validate against an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```